# this is runtime error transform DexArchive with external library

Tags: android

## this is the runtime error

> *Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex*

## this is build apk dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.stepstone.apprating:app-rating:2.2.0'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
compile 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'

//compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[4,5)')
compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
// implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:11.8.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
// compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
// implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:11.8.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'

compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: remove `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'` too

Comment: Remove all libraries which are already inside Support Design library https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html

Comment: i just removed all librarry which is in support design.but still same problem

Comment: please tell me solution